# Javascript OOM error

Tags: javascript

New to JS here, so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious. Trying to build a random number generator (it works in a nested manner, so something like a list of tuples of random number), but I get a OOM error with this code. (Say, if i try to do something like generateList(6))

```
function generateList(num){
  var arr = [];
  for(i=0;i<num;i++){
    arr.push(generateTuple());
  }
  return arr;
}

function generateTuple(){
  var tuple = [];

  for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    tuple.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 300));
  }
  return '(' + tuple[0] + ',' + tuple[1] + ',' + tuple[2] + ')';
}
```

OTOH, if I just generate the random numbers individually and return them (instead of using a list), it works without errors. Can anyone enlighten me as to what is going on here?

```
function generateTuple(){
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300);


    return '(' + a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ')';
}
```

EDIT: So basically if you run the code, it gets stuck in some loop, and after a period of time in the console it returns the OOM error. So I assume it's some memory overflow or something somewhere.

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: @Rayon Try to run his code, you'll see pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i`s are global variables. Always declare variables with `const` or `let` (or `var`) to avoid global pollution and unexpected behavior (like what's happening here).

Each time `generateTuple` is run, `i` gets set to 3 at the end of the `for` loop in `generateTuple`. So, the `i` referenced by `generateList` - which references the same global variable - never has a chance to get any higher than 4. So if you call `generateList` with higher numbers, you'll get an infinite loop.

Just declare your variables properly:

```js
 function generateList(num){
    var arr = [];
    for(let i=0;i<num;i++){
        arr.push(generateTuple());
    }
    return arr;
}

function generateTuple(){
    var tuple = [];

    for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
        tuple.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 300));
    }
    return '(' + tuple[0] + ',' + tuple[1] + ',' + tuple[2] + ')';
}

console.log(generateList(10));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating global `i` by declaring it without var or let, then you loop with it. That creates unprecedented values for `i`, leading to the loop will never complete. Declare your variables correctly.

```
for(var i=0;i<num;i++) // better: let i = 0; ...
```

and

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++) // better: let i = 0; ...
```